# Minimization of the volume of the image of space-filling convex polytopes under similarities

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, orbifolds

Suppose $A:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a similarity, given by $A(x) = \lambda Ox$, where $\lambda > 1$ and $O$ is an orthogonal matrix (i.e., $A$ is a particular loxodromic repelling uniformly quasiconformal map).  Further, suppose $U$ is a space filling convex polytope.  Here, $U$ is realized as the fundamental domain for an orientation-preserving crystallographic group $G$, and $A$ satisfies $A^{-1} G A \subset G$.  This then means that the vertices of $A(U)$ must be mapped into the lattice $\Lambda$ generated by the maximal translation subgroup of $G$.

For $n \geq 3$, how can we compute $\inf_{A,U}\frac{|A(U)|}{|U|}$, where the infimum is taken over all space filling polyhedra $U$ and similarities $A$ satisfying the required condition?

If $n = 2$, then we can take $U$ to be the square $[0,1]^2$, and $G$ is a $(p2)$ crystallographic group with integer lattice $\mathbb{Z} + i \mathbb{Z}$ and fundamental domain given by $U$.  Here, we can take $A(z) = (1+i)z$ (rotation of order $8$ composed with a dilation by $\sqrt{2}$).  Hence, $|A(U)|/|U| = 2$ in this case, and the vertices of $A(U)$ are mapped into the lattice $\mathbb{Z} + i \mathbb{Z}$.  To my knowledge, the infimum of $|A(U)|/|U|$ in dimension $2$ is exactly $2$, if $A^{-1}GA \subset G$, and $U$ is a fundamental domain for $G$.

For $n \geq 3$, the best I can do so far is show the obvious, i.e. that $\inf_{A,U}|A(U)|/|U|\leq 2^n$.  Any suggestions on how to attack this problem?  Any help is greatly appreciated.